# TypeScript - export library with 'namespaces'

Tags: typescript, module

Ok, so for example I have a project with following file structure:

[image: file structure]

Let the project be called 'my-module'

I'd like import this library to other project like that:

```
import { User, Home } from 'my-module/Models'
import { BaseWindow } from 'my-module/View'
```

How I can do that? How to prepare .d.ts file?

EDIT:

[Project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-zei4ve)

Content of the above files are simple for example:

```
interface IUser {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

type UserOptions = IUser & {
  foo: string
}

class User implements IUser {
  private foo: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  constructor(options: UserOptions) {
    this.name = options.name;
    this.age = options.age;
    this.foo = options.foo;
  }
}

export { User, UserOptions };
```

Comment: If these imports have runtime content (e.g., a class and not just an interface), you'll need a `.ts` file, not just a `.d.ts` file.  Its location needs to match the import path you want to use.  I.e., you'd create `src/Models/index.ts` and `src/View/index.ts` files that import the necessary items from the source files shown in the picture and re-export them as named exports.  I can provide the content of the wrapper `.ts` file for you if you add the exports of your existing source files to the question.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I would be grateful to show you an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing what you want in `src/Models/index.ts` is:

```
export * from "./User";
export * from "./Home";
```

Then, assuming you have module resolution set up appropriately, you can write:

```
import { User, UserOptions } from "my-module/Models";
```

and `User` and `UserOptions` will refer to the class and the type alias from `src/Models/User.ts`, respectively.  If `src/Models/User.ts` and `src/Models/Home.ts` declare a symbol with the same name, I believe the first `export *` statement wins.

### Module resolution issue

If an import of `my-module/` is giving you completions of `src` and `dist`, then you would need to import the full relative path to the `.js` and `.d.ts` files (which should be next to each other).  I assume these files are under `dist`.  If you don't like the `dist` in your import path, you have a few options, none of them great:

1. Don't use `src` and `dist` directories; arrange all files starting from the root of the project.
2. Use a module bunder or loader that you can customize so that `import "my-module/Models"` looks in the `dist` folder.  If your bundler or loader doesn't already integrate with TypeScript, use TypeScript's [path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) options to make TypeScript's module resolution behavior mirror that of your bundler or loader.
3. Redirect each import path individually to the proper files under `dist` by manually creating either a pair of `.js` and `.d.ts` files that import the real paths or a `package.json` file with `main` and `types` fields that refer to the real paths.

Comment: I suppose I have problem with module resolution (it's new topic for me) because in other project when I type `my-module/` I see folders dist, node_modules and src. I also do not know what I should type in `src/index.ts`. Is `import './Models` enough?

Comment: I updated the answer to discuss module resolution.  You don't have to put anything in `src/index.ts` unless you want to import from it, in which case what you put there would depend on how you want to write the imports.